# Getting input from multiple forms by modal in laravel

Tags: laravel, forms, bootstrap-modal

Im pretty new to web development, im creating basic CRUD for my intern project. My client asked me to make a single create form where i need to upload those input to database, lets say i have 3 table : Shops,Fruits (one shop has many fruits), and Vegetables (one shop has many vegetables)

I ended up making multiple forms, which one main form for the shop input, and some additional form inside modal for fruits and vegetables input (forms are separated).
After submitting and passing to controller, i can only get input from shop form and not the others.

Scripts and styles:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Adding and removing fruit table row
        $(".fruit-add").click(function(){
            var fruit_pic = $("#fruit_pic").val();
            var fruit_pic_name = $("#fruit_pic").val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '')
            var fruit_name = $("#fruit_name").val();
            var markup = "<tr><td>" + fruit_pic_name + "</td><td>" + fruit_name + "</td><td>" + "<button type='button' class='fruit-remove'> Delete </button>" +  "</td></tr>";
            $(".fruit-table").append(markup);
        });
        $("body").on("click",".fruit-remove",function(){
            $(this).parents("tr").remove();
        });
        //Adding and removing vegetable table row
        $(".vegetable-add").click(function(){
            var vegetable_pic = $("#vegetable_pic").val();
            var vegetable_pic_name = $("#vegetable_pic").val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '')
            var vegetable_name = $("#vegetable_name").val();
            var markup = "<tr><td>" + vegetable_pic_name + "</td><td>" + vegetable_name + "</td><td>" + "<button type='button' class='vegetable-remove'> Delete </button>" +  "</td></tr>";
            $(".vegetable-table").append(markup);
        });
        $("body").on("click",".vegetable-remove",function(){
            $(this).parents("tr").remove();
        });
    });     
</script>
```

My shop form:

```html
<form method="post" action="/add-shop/store" id="addShop" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="shop_name">Shop name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="shop_name"  id="shop_name" aria-describedby="shop_name">
        @if($errors->has('shop_name'))
            <div class="text-danger">
                {{ $errors->first('shop_name')}}
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label> Fruits </label>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Picture</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="fruit-table">
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- Button trigger fruit modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addFruit">
            Add fruit
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label> Vegetables </label>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Picture</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="vegetable-table">
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- Button trigger vegetable modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addVegetable">
            Add vegetable
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My forms on popup modal:

```html
<!-- Fruit Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addFruit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addFruit" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <form id="form_fruit">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="addFruit">Fruit</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fruit_pic">Picture</label>
                        <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="fruit_pic[]" id="fruit_pic" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fruit_name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="fruit_name[]" class="form-control" id="fruit_name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary fruit-add" data-dismiss="modal">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Vegetable Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addVegetable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addVegetavle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <form id="form_vegetable">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="addVegetable">Vegetable</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="vegetable_pic">Picture</label>
                        <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="vegetable_pic[]" id="vegetable_pic" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="vegetable_name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vegetable_name[]" id="vegetable_name" placeholder="Deskripsi">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary vegetable-add" data-dismiss="modal">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller functions:

```php
public function add()
{
    return view('add-shop');
}

public function storeTest(Request $request)
{
    echo "test\n"; //works
    echo $request->fruit_name; //doest work
    if($request->hasfile('fruit_pic')){ //doesnt work
        foreach($request->file('fruit_pic') as $image){
            echo $request->fruit_name; 
        }
    }
    echo $request->shop_name; //work
}
```

When i try to submit the form, i get the shop_name but not all the other form attributes (fruits and vegetables)

I have the feeling that my method is not quite right, what is wrong and is there a better way to applicate this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just taking a quick look at the form you should use at the action

```
{{url(}}
{{route()}}
```

your not getting the shop form because the model it self is not in the form make sure to put it in the same `form` where you submit the original form tag. alternative if you really want to have it outside you can make a hidden input in the form and put there your data in with java script from the model and then submit the form

Answer (score -1):

do this also to the --vegetable modal--:

```
<!-- Fruit Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addFruit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addFruit" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <form id="form_fruit" method="post" action="{{ url('/add-fruits') }}">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="addFruit">Fruit</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fruit_pic">Picture</label>
                        <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="fruit_pic[]" id="fruit_pic" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fruit_name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="fruit_name" class="form-control" id="fruit_name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary fruit-add" data-dismiss="modal">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller

```
public function addFruits(Request $request)
{
$this->validate($request, [

          'fruit_name'      => 'required|string',
          'fruit_pic.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,gif,png,bmp|max:8300',
             ]);

       $fruitname=$request->input('fruit_name');

     if($request->hasfile('fruit_pic'))
                   {
                      foreach($request->file('fruit_pic') as $file)
                      {
                         $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
                          $file->move(public_path().'/../../example.com/images', $name);

                         DB::table('tblfruits')->insert([
                         'fruit_name' => $fruitname,
                         'fruit_pic' => $name,
                         ]);


                      }
                   }
}
```

route

```
Route::post('/add-fruits','Controller@addFruits');
```

Comment: i use foreach because from your fileupload, its clear that you are uploading multiple files. you have to write separate store functions and route for the three forms. your initial forms only use /add-shop/store for shopForm reason for the error. remember also to add enctype="multipart/form-data" to the modal forms